# Why is this wood on my drill bit from wall framing a different color?

Tags: wood, drill-bit

I was installing some new blinds and when I drilled into the framing above the window my drill bit had a darker color wood dust on it. Other places I have drilled at the dust is the standard wood color but this was darker and sticky. Any idea why?

[image]

Comment: What year is the home? What region are you in? About when were the windows installed? The opening may be refurbished, with rotted sills or stoops replaced with newer lumber . Wood darkens with age, but isn't necessarily rotten.

Comment: What is "standard wood color"? Have you _looked_ at a pine board lately? :P

Comment: You hit a knot.

Answer (score 15):

Since you mentioned it was sticky, You probably drilled through a knot in the wood or hit a wood sap pocket. If the screws go in tight, you shouldn't have a problem.

Comment: Darker wood could simply be from hitting a knot in the board.